# What kind of 3x2 connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification

Does anybody know what kind of connectors these are?

- The size of the holes on the right picture is about 5 mm
- The inner size of the holes on the left picture is about 3 mm

[image]

Comment: It uses crimpable male and female inserts if that helps narrow things down.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks ... I doubt I can ever use them, but I'm curious (and always good to learn).

Comment: What's the pitch? i.e. centre to centre of the holes. Is it the row spacing the same pitch?

Comment: @TomCarpenter around 6mm (which fits with your answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They appear to be Molex "MLX" power connectors (series 42021).

[image: Molex MLX Connector Image]

[Here](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0050841065_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml) is the 6-way variant pictured above, part number 50-84-1065.

They are designed for 2.13mm pins, which fits the ~3mm hole measurement. They have a pitch of 6.35mm, which matches with the ~6mm measurement.

Comment: Confirmed that the pitch is around 6mm :-) ... thank you; I never saw these before.

Answer (score 5):

This connector series is also available in the old AMP line that is now supplied by TE connectivity. Their series is called the Universal MATE-N-LOCK.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture source at [Digikey Product Page](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/350848-6/A25735-ND/332917))*</sup>

In today's use of much lower power in most gadgets and devices these connectors are being used less and less. I still like to use them for power delivery because of their relative low cost and higher current carrying capacity per pin over other 2.54mm contact spacing connectors and headers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe I can use them in case I want to use multiple LED strips.